# ERROR: function postgis_lib_version() does not exist when matching a postgis custom schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, geoserver

I have a rails app with a PostGIS database running in docker containners. I'm using [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for multitenancy and [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) to access the PostGIS geospatial database features from ActiveRecord. I have PostGIS installed in `shared_extentions` schema as the apartment docs suggest. When I try to configure a datastore in geoserver I get the following error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: ERROR: function postgis_lib_version() does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 8
```

Geoserver datastore connection parameters:

```
host: app-db
port: 5432
database: app_development
schema: shared_extensions
user: 
passwd:
```

*database.yml*:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  postgis_schema: shared_extensions
  schema_search_path: public, shared_extensions
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  host: app-db
  username:
  password:
```

*lib/tasks/db_enhancements.rake*:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Also create shared_extensions Schema'
  task :extensions => :environment  do
    # Create Schema
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Hstore
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS HSTORE SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Postgis
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable UUID-OSSP
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Grant usage to public
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'GRANT usage ON SCHEMA shared_extensions to public;'
  end
end
```

I've also tried it on pgAdmin with `SELECT shared_extensions.postgis_version()` and it works fine:

```
2.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

But of course when I run `SELECT postgis_version()` I get:

```
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LÍNEA 1: SELECT postgis_version()
                ^
SUGERENCIA:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoServer expects PostGIS to be installed in the public schema does not prepend `shared_extensions` to it's postgis functions. If you want to do this then you need to add `shared_extensions` to the search path so that GeoServer can find the functions it will need.

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET 'search_path' = public,shared_extension;
```

See this [note](https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/) for details on how to move postgis to a different schema.

Comment: Shouldn't this be set when I specify `schema_search_path: public, shared_extensions` in `database.yml`? I mean, I don't want to configure it from the database but from my Rails configuration file

Comment: If it was set then you wouldn't be seeing this error message

Comment: As I specified in the description, the `schema_search_path: public, shared_extensions` is set in the `database.yml`, although it's not being applied when I create the database, apparently this is the error, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: No idea, but it isn't a geoserver problem

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have installed PostGIS Extention with Postgresql

or

for checking you can create PostGIS Extension for database in pgadmin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).